# Not showing a picture where table field is empty

Tags: php

I have a MTSQL database where up to 25 images can be stored, in table fields called picture1 through to picture 25.

What i want to do is check these variables once they are pulled from the database to see whether they should be displayed or not.

currently if there isn't an images it still shows and you just get the missing image sign.  And no matter what i seem to write it shows regardless off if there is an image or not, below is my current code.

```
   <? if(!isset($picture2) || empty($picture2)){ ?

    <div class="property-slide">
    <a href="m/properties/<?php echo $row['picture2']; ?>" class="image-popup">
    <img alt="" src="m/properties/<?php echo $row['picture2']; ?>"></a>
    </div>

    <? } ?>
```

The value of picture 2 is currently just 1.jpg which is located in a folder on the server at the path m/properties/.

I did consider storing all the images seperatley, which would be easier as i could use a query to show all relevant properties,  but this was pre built by somebody else and the database is populated from a third party api.

Comment: You're going to have to show more code for anyone to understand.

Comment: What's the value of `$picture2`? Usually you would check if it exists then display it. Now you're checking if it does not exist. I would use `&&` and `empty` also includes `isset` internally.

Comment: As above, we need to see more code, including the html with the `img` tag. Also, as a side note, you probably want to normalize your database and separate images into their own table, linked via foreign key

Comment: What do you store inside of `$picture2`, what do you do in that block `if`? Please give us more information so we can help you.

Comment: What do you see in the source code if there is no image? The only thing i can think of is either the variable `$picture2` contains something thats not an image url, or your server isnt using short tags (so is ignoring `<? ...`